# Javascript to build mvc actionlink conditionally

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is in a VB.NET MVC 3 Razor view and fires when a JsonResult of success is returned. The problem is that I would like to conditionally build an actionlink if `data.Object.Status == 'Completed';`

I have looked around and nothing seems to be fitting at all to solve this. This is what the actionlink should look like in razor:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Completed(Print Cert)", "Ind_Cert", "Printing", New With {.firstName = currentItem.firstName, .lastname = currentItem.lastName, .classRef = currentItem.course_ref, .cNumber = currentItem.conf_number}, Nothing)
```

And this is the javascript function that will do it. Currently it just Places the contents of `data.Object.Status`. Which should only show like that when `data.Object.Status != 'Completed'`;

```
  function updateSuccess(data) {
    if (data.Success == true) {
        //we update the table's info
        var parent = linkObj.closest("tr");
        parent.find(".CompletedClass").html(data.Object.Status);
        //now we can close the dialog
        $('#updateDialog').dialog('close');
        //twitter type notification
        $('#commonMessage').html("Update Complete");
        $('#commonMessage').delay(400).slideDown(400).delay(3000).slideUp(400);
    }
    else {
        $("#update-message").html(data.ErrorMessage);
        $("#update-message").show();
    }
}
```

Below is what I am thinking will work I am still trying to figure it out but this is a rough markup of it.

```
   function updateSuccess(data) {
    if (data.Success == true) {
        //we update the table's info
        var parent = linkObj.closest("tr");
        var d = parent.find(".CompletedClass");
        if (data.Object.Status == 'Completed') {
            d.html = @Html.ActionLink("Completed(Print Cert)", "Ind_Cert", "Printing", New With {.firstName = Model(0).firstName, .lastname = Model(0).lastName, .classRef = Model(0).Completed_Class, .cNumber = Model(0).conf_number}, Nothing) 
            }


        //now we can close the dialog
        $('#updateDialog').dialog('close');
        //twitter type notification
        $('#commonMessage').html("Update Complete");
        $('#commonMessage').delay(400).slideDown(400).delay(3000).slideUp(400);
    }
    else {
        $("#update-message").html(data.ErrorMessage);
        $("#update-message").show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you suggest right now should work, there is a typo on your code assigning the HTML, you probably know it but the way you add HTML to an element is (You have a = sign which is not valid) :

```
d.html (@Html.ActionLink("Completed(Print Cert)", "Ind_Cert", ....)
```

Assuming is an element that accepts html, otherwise, use the "text" function.

In any case, my recommendation would be to generate the HTML before hand but have it hidden on the page (unless you have thousands of them, of there are security concerns). Then you just have your Javascript simply show the element:

```
 var parent = linkObj.closest("tr");
 var linkElement = parent.find(".mylinkelement-class");
    if (data.Object.Status == 'Completed') {
        linkElement.show();
        }
```

This should give you the benefit of allowing better separation between your Javascript and your MVC code.

HTH,
-Covo

Comment: Thanks greatly i would have never picked up on the `=` as I am really new to `javascript`. But yes this view shows a 1 to many list so I have no way of building those links in a good manner.

Answer (score 1):

You should update your code to something like this

```
d.html('@Html.ActionLink("Completed(Print Cert)", "Ind_Cert", "Printing", New With {.firstName = Model(0).firstName, .lastname = Model(0).lastName, .classRef = Model(0).Completed_Class, .cNumber = Model(0).conf_number}, Nothing)');
```

To assign html with jQuery you should use `jQuery.html()`.

The Razor `@Html.ActionLink` will print HTML to the page, to not break your Javascript, put those inside quotes `d.html('@Html...')`

Comment: is it possible to assign those route values `{.firstName = Model(0).firstName, .lastname = Model(0).lastName, .classRef = Model(0).Completed_Class, .cNumber = Model(0).conf_number}` using javascript? I basically need to get those from the `data.Object.???`

Comment: As a hack I am setting temp variables in the razor view with javascript then getting those values using `@variableName` I know that is a messy way when I should be able to do it with straight javascript.

Comment: @Skindeep2366, it is possible to return your URL from the Json and use it directly on the HTML. There are also other ways to expose your map routes as a big Javascript object that output client-side.

Comment: Thanks much. I actually ended up just creating the `<a href>` link myself in the `d.html line.